# geom_text does not appear using scale_y_log10

Tags: r, text, ggplot2, geom-text

I can add text to a ggplot using `geom_text` just fine (example using the cars database):

```
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist), color='blue') + 
geom_point(size=0.8) + 
geom_text(y=25, x=5, aes(label=paste("sigma == 1"), size=1.5), 
    hjust=0, parse=TRUE, color='blue')
```

But when I change the y scale to logarithmic, I can not get the text to appear on the graph:

```
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist), color='blue') + 
geom_point(size=0.8) + 
geom_text(y=25, x=5, aes(label=paste("sigma == 1"), size=1.5), 
    hjust=0, parse=TRUE, color='blue') + 
scale_y_log10()
```

I've tried varying the text size and position but can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me:

```
require(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist), color='blue')
g <- g + geom_point(size=0.8)
g <- g + geom_text(aes(y=25, x=5, label=paste("sigma == 1"), size=1.5), hjust=0, parse=TRUE, color='blue')
g <- g + scale_y_log10()
g
```

Comment: Interesting and odd.  That works for me.  And now, when I reissue the commands as I did above, that too is working.  Very strange.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well then it was just the y=25 and x=5 being outside the aes which gave ggplot a hickup...

Answer (score 3):

This works better:

```
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist), color='blue') + 
    geom_point(size=0.8) + 
    geom_text(y=2, x=5, aes(label=paste("sigma == 1"), size=1.5), 
        hjust=0, parse=TRUE, color='blue') + 
    scale_y_log10()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP6FS.png)

Normal to log scale: 100 -> 2; 1000 -> 3; 0.1 -> -1; 0.01 -> -2

Comment: I like the idea of feeding the positions in on the scale of data and using the scales machinery to do the log transformations, rather than computing.

Answer (score 2):

The issue in the original code is that the x and y values are not wrapped up by aes(), so the axis transformation is not applied to them.  To fix, just move the aes() to include all the aesthetics.

```
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist), color='blue') + 
  geom_point(size=0.8) + 
  geom_text(aes(y=25, x=5, label=paste("sigma == 1"), size=1.5), 
            hjust=0, parse=TRUE, color='blue') + 
  scale_y_log10()
```

Comment: Even though the solution here is the same as the accepted answer, I think this is much better as it includes the explanation.